# how to interpret scala mixed identifiers

Tags: scala

I have some code below

```
   val primitiveDS = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDS()
   primitiveDS.map(_ + 1).collect() // Returns: Array(2, 3, 4)
```

I want to know what exactly underscore meaning here (**_** + 1), I know this belongs to scala mixed identifiers, I searched lot but could not get the exact meaning.

Also share some link to get it in depth of

Answer (score 0):

`map(x=>x+1)` short form is `map(_+1)`. It is a short form to access the element

Comment: Could you please point to some document to understand more about these

Comment: How to understand this------------ 
ranks
  .join(stationVertices)
  .sortBy(_._2._1, ascending=false) // sort by the rank
  .take(10) // get the top 10
  .foreach(x => println(x._2._2))